# Computing pairs of integers that satisfy $x^2+y^2\equiv 1 \mod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, computer-science

The algebraic formula for the unit circle is centered at the origin is:

$$x^2+y^2=1$$

This equation is easy to generalize to any field. I'm interested in the unit circle for modular fields. Specifically, given a base $n$, we can define the unit circle $C_n$ as the set of points

$$C_n=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\;\vert\; x^2+y^2\equiv 1 \mod n \}$$

What's the fastest way to compute a list of all the points in the set $C_n$ (restricting ourselves to $x$ and $y$ being in the range $[0,n-1]$)? Are there any methods that run faster than $O(n^2)$?

Comment: you can a get linear time algorithm if you store all different remainders modulo $n$ in a hashmap, for which there are at most $n/2$ distinct remainders.

Comment: You say "fields": is $n$ then supposed to be a prime?

Comment: We can easily restrict ourselves to $0\leq x,y\leq \frac n2$ instead. That shaves off $75\%$ of the cases to check compared to the bound you have.

Comment: Note that this is only a field when $n$ is prime, but you might want solutions when $\mathbb Z_n$ is not a field...

Answer (score 0):

The parametric solution $$x = \frac{2s}{s^2+1}, \ y = \frac{s^2-1}{s^2+1} $$
works over any field (for $s$ such that $s^2+1 \ne 0$, of course).  Only $x=0, y=1$ is not covered by this.   This lets you enumerate all the solutions over any finite field in time linear in the cardinality (assuming each arithmetic operation in the field takes $O(1)$ time).